# Running separate process in ASP.NET Core Web Minimal API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, asp.net-core-minimal-hosting-model

I have a long running process that I would like to add a REST api to. Through the API I would like to be able to inspect the values of variables inside the long running process.

I put together a proof of concept using minimal API:

```
public class Program
{
    public static int val = 0;
    public static object locker = new object();


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    val++;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var app = builder.Build();

        app.MapGet("/", () => 
        {
            lock (locker)
                return val;
        });

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

My idea is to have the code for my long running process running inside of the Task.Run. Am I going about this the right way? Are there any potential pitfalls/gotchas to what Im trying to do?

Comment: Will your code be running in the cloud ?

Comment: potentially. does it make a difference?

Comment: Some host kill apps after a period from the last request

Comment: If you run on Azure, I would probably guide you towards Durable Functions. You can keep a state, you can check for a running task state, you can run several tasks at the same time, with parameters, and so on and so forth. It's really powerful. But it has a dependency on an Azure Storage Account to be able to maintain its state.

Comment: I'd prefer to have this run on my local server instead of using a custom cloud solution

Comment: Since you already have a long running process ready - it makes sense to run web app in separate thread, not your process (so, using `app.RunAsync`). Then your app flow is unchanged.

Comment: @David what is the *real* problem? I've been in a similar situation - I created a CLI tool that does a long-running job and run it on a schedule. Then I had to add an API so users could kick it off from a web page. And now ... I'm adding RabbitMQ so they can send every single request at once instead of submitting one big batch. What you do depends on what the API is meant to do and what the job does

Answer (score 5):

You could create a service that holds the state, and you can access that service from your API. A windows service/hosted service is great for a "long-running process", and it can host your API: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-and-manage-the-windows-service).

**ValueService.cs**

Implement `BackgroundService` for your long running process.

```
public class ValueService : BackgroundService
{
    private int _val;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _val; }
        set { _val = value; }
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {        

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), stoppingToken);
            Value++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

Register your service and register retrieval from the service provider.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ValueService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService(p => p.GetService<ValueService>()!);

var app = builder.Build();
```

Inject service in your API:

```
app.MapGet("/", (ValueService valueService) =>
{
    return valueService.Value;       
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: do you need to do a lock on valueService.Value?

Comment: @David you absolutely do need to lock it.

Comment: Unless you write the service in a way that doesn't need it, eg using `Interlocked.Add`. In real applications you can get rid of this by using eg job/work queues and a controlled number of workers to process jobs/messages